# System Design Question (Twitter Snowflake)

Tags: mysql

At companyA we want to assign an unique id for each type of event (for example, given a new user id for each user signs up, or assign a new trip id for each new trip taking place). besides the uniqueness requirements, we also has other requirements:

1. the system must be highly performant and scalable, it may need to handle high number of RPS (for example we have 14MM+ trips per day, and peak days have even larger numbers)
2. the system must have very high availability as well, and no SPOF etc.
3. the ids should be roughly sequential. but we are ok with some gaps in the ids which were
4. generated, means the id does not need to be strictly sequential like 1,2,3,4.
   the id space should be big enough - for example 64 bit number will do, but 32 bit number will not (companyA will have more than 10B or 100B trips, 32 bits number are not large enough)

Comment: You mention "Twitter Snowflake" and "MySQL" only in the title and tags, not in the body.  Can you explain the connection to MySQL and Twitter Snowflake in your question? Did you consider a solution similar to Twitter Snowflake, where each computer (server) responsible for assigning trip IDs is given a unique number that forms part of that ID?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [Time based GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)), which is generated, in part, from a timestamp.